# Recently-opened documents option in QGIS

Tags: qgis-2

Is there a recent documents option somewhere in QGIS similar to other software? Or do people always use add layers / drag and drop from the Browser, or ensure that  all is saved as a project each time? Looks like the Project option is basically the same as the .WOR file in MapInfo which I'm very familiar with. Very handy but can be a bit of a pain if files start moving round...

I've just had QGIS hanging up on me a few times when experimenting and requiring restart of program. A recently opened option would be nice. Not a priority and I know the spinning wheel usually means lose of record of last file opened, not saved, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to add your layers/data and save a map file (.qgs extension). There is an 'Open Recent' option in the file menu for your recently opened map files. A QGIS project would be the equivalent of a MapInfo Workspace as your have mentioned.

By 'recently opened' I assume you mean recently used data. In which case if you are adding data from PostGIS you can save the connection information to make adding layers quicker.

[image]

Comment: Cheers Matt, couldn't see it for looking.